# Hide all divs of a certain class with C# in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor, webassembly

I have `Page.razor` which looks like this:

```html
<div class="foo">bar</div>
<div class="wing">dings</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="HideFooClass">Hide Foo Class</button>
```

What C# code could be used for `HideFooClass` that could be modified to hide wing instead if the code was adapted?

Currently I make class a variable, `fooVisibility`. `HideFooClass` then changes the value of `fooVisibility` to one of a class with the CSS property `visibility: hidden`. I would prefer to be able to make a generic `HideClass` method which takes would take the string `foo` to replace `HideFooClass` so I could use it to hide the `wing` class.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is pass an argument that tells what class to hide. Then for each element in the class (I presume there *can* be many because you used a `class` not `id`), you add another class called `hidden`. Then in CSS, you just set `display: none` for the `hidden` class.

This way any element with the `hidden` class will be hidden for good, until you of course remove it.

So you do this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick='() => HideClass("foo")'> Hide Foo Class</button>
```

Then in the HideClass method, you have the same logic, but instead you add the `hidden` class to all elements with that class.

Do know that you can actually do this in plain JS which is MUCH better, because normally with blazor you will have to call a JS method via c#, which is just extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need a CSS to hide the class.
You can use Blazor to do this work for you.

Anyway, if you prefer this approach you can call the methods like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => Hide("foo"))>Hide Foo Class</button>
```

if you need to receive the original *args* use this form:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(args => Hide("foo", args))>Hide Foo Class</button>
```

and the methods will be:

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
...
public async Task Hide(string element, MouseEventArgs args) 
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("SiteFunctions.hideElement", element);
}
```

now you need a javascript, referenced in you `<head>` tag, with this content:

```
window.SiteFunctions = window.SiteFunctions || {
hideElement: function (id) {
        $("." + id).hide();
// or without jquery
        var ele = document.getElementByClassName(id); 
        ele.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative Blazor approaches - it depends where all the Foo divs are.

1. Method 1 uses a component with a show hide to show or hide the content within the component.
2. Method 2 uses the same approach but adds/hides some css.

The demo page shows the two methods in action.

###### DivComponent

```
@if (this.Show)
{
    <div @attributes="this.UserAttributes">
        @this.ChildContent
    </div>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> UserAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

###### CssComponent

```
@if (this.Show)
{
    <style>
        .foo {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }
}
```

###### Demo Page

```
@page "/Test10"
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_foo" class="bg-danger text-white m-2 p-2">bar</DivComponent>
<DivComponent Show="_wing" class="bg-success text-white m-2 p-2">dings</DivComponent>
<CSSComponent Show="_css" />
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => { _foo = !_foo; }">Show/Hide Foo</button>
<button class="btn btn-success ms-2" @onclick="() => { _wing = !_wing; }">Show/Hide Ding</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning ms-2" @onclick="() => { _css = !_css; }">Show/Hide CSS</button>

@code {
    private bool _foo;
    private bool _wing;
    private bool _css;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this, but don't.  Presumably you won't be turning divs on and off just for the helluvit-- you'll be hiding and showing components or elements based on change in state.

In Blazor, you should use C# to test for the desired change of state, and avoid using JS and CSS unnecessarily.

```
<button @onclick='()=>foo=true'>Show</button>

@if (foo)
{
    <div class="fooformatting">@bar</div>
}

@code {
    string bar = "I have revealed my true form";
    bool foo;
}
```

There are zero cases where I've ever had to use JavaScript to hide and show elements in Blazor.  Note that `fooformatting` is now being used only to format `bar` with CSS, not as a hack to let jQuery find the div and toggle its visibility.